# working with variables from dispatch_async

Tags: ios, arrays, grand-central-dispatch

I have a method which downloads some pics from a server. I had the buffer for the downloaded data defined withing async block (NSMutableArray *imgtmp) but haven't figured out how to get the array back out of there. What's the best way to access imgtmp in order to return it's contents, or set an instance variable from it?

I've been looking in the [Apple Block docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html) but I must not be in the right section. Do I need to declare imgtmp using the `__block` keyword somehow? I tried that but imgtmp was still empty outside the block. Thanks!

**EDIT**: code updated with working model

```
- (void) loadImages
{
   // temp array for downloaded images. If all downloads complete, load into the actual image data array for tablerows
   __block NSMutableArray *imgtmp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0),
   ^{
      int error = 0;
      int totalitems = 0;
      NSMutableArray *picbuf = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

      for (int i=0; i < _imageURLS.count;i++)
      {
         NSLog(@"loading image for main image holder at index %i",i);
         NSURL *mynsurl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[_imageURLS objectAtIndex:i]];
         NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:mynsurl];
         UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];


         if (img)
         {
            [picbuf addObject:img];
            totalitems++;
         }
         else
         {
            NSLog(@"error loading img from %@", [_imageURLS objectAtIndex:i]);
            error++;
         }
      }// for int i...


      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
      ^{
         NSLog(@"_loadedImages download COMPLETE");
         imgtmp = picbuf;
         [_tvStatus setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d objects have been retrieved", totalitems]];
         NSLog (@"imgtmp contains %u images", [imgtmp count]);
      });// get_main_queue


   });// get_global_queue


}
```

Comment: dispatch async returns immediately. and you are continuing to the NSLog before your block is even executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're hitting that "final" `NSLog` call *before* any of your block code has executed.  All your image loading stuff is wrapped in a dispatch_async.  It is executed *asynchronously* whereas the NSLog is called right away.

I think the best thing for you to do is to pass imgtmp along to some persistent object.  Perhaps your view controller can have a property like:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *images;
```

and you can assign that in the same block where you assign the text to `_tvStatus`.

Comment: Ahh.. I should have known. Thanks for the answer! code updated.

Comment: Note that if you're mutating state from another queue, you'll need some form of synchronization around the mutation... whether that's an atomic property (probably not enough), a serial dispatch queue, or a lock.

Comment: Not sure what you mean (new to ios development) but I think you are saying to take measures when accessing the *images property to ensure two methods are not writing to it at the same time, yes? (as well as making sure loadImages method has completed updating *images property before actually reading data from it)

Comment: Yup. Generally speaking it's safe to have any number of readers *or* one writer at any given time.