# Load array into a tableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I do this all the time but for some reason its not working for me today.

The cells are empty , here is my code:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return [self.messageArray count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell..
    NSString *messageAtIndexPath = [messageArray objectAtIndex :[indexPath row]];
    [[cell textLabel] setText:messageAtIndexPath];

    return cell;
}
```

I made sure everything (Delegate and Source) is connected properly.

If I hardcode stuff for example:

```
return 5;
```

and

```
[[cell textLabel] setText:@"this is a cell"];
```

Then its working , so I am not sure whats up. Also my array is populated I can see it in the log console.

EDIT:

```
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSString *postString = @"controller=Push&action=GetPushAlerts&accountId=123";
    NSData *JsonData = [ApiCaller post :postString];
    NSDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    //parsing JSON

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        BOOL success = [result[@"success"] boolValue];
        if(success){
            // Account exists, parse the data
            NSDictionary *data = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
            messageArray = [data objectForKey:@"message"];

           // NSLog(@"count %@", message);

        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Try to debug, or your array is empty or its content

Comment: Why are you doing deque:forIndexPath? I always just deque with identifier. Also, contents of messageArray?

Comment: Delegate and data source for tableview set? Tableview outlet linked?

Comment: how are you initializing your nsarray?

Comment: @DaviStuart, its not empty its a bunch of strings

Comment: Are your cells set to custom style, or one of the standard styles?

Comment: @Gavin Its set to custom

Comment: i think you need to call reloadData method after filling your array it will work.

Comment: @freenalcer whats the code for that, strange I never had to do that

Comment: If the hardcoded version works, it must be because of the array then. The text color of the label is white / clearcolor? What do you get if you log the messageString?

Comment: [tableview reloadData]; But that shouldn't be the case, unless you get the data asynchronously.

Comment: [MYUITableViewOBJ reloadData]

Comment: @LordZsolt I am so sorry guys I forgot to mention I was loading it asynchronously , Do I need to reload it? how?

Comment: Yes you do. Put [self.tableview reloadData] after messageArray = [data objectForKey:@"message"]; in the "if(success)" block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to wrap things up: If you're loading data asynchronously, you MUST reload the table View (Or anything that displays the data and is drawn before the data arrives), because when a view loads, it displays according to the data it has at THAT instant.

To do this, add the following command to where the data arrives (usually into the success block, unless you want to display some data on the failure block as well):

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

If on the other hand, the call is synchronous (rarely used), it hangs the application where the call is executed (usually in viewDidLoad), so the display is only drawn after the data arrived, thus having data to display.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was my first time to load it asynchronously, I did not realized I had to reload the data. Lesson learned!

Comment: Quick question do you know how to return NSData from `dispatch_async(queue, ^{}` , if not I will post new question

Comment: Glad I could help :) Took me like two days to write my first asynchronous request, so you're doing good :)

Comment: Well, I haven't worked directly with GCD too much, but you need to write a callback block or use a delegate.

Comment: Take a look at this answer, it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18922379/working-with-variables-from-dispatch-async

Comment: Thanks this was helpful, so much I still have to learn oh well don't we all lol

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the cells are defined as static in IB rather than dynamic? You should check that first.

Comment: You should put these hunches in a comment rather then an answer. If it's right, you'll make an answer after to get it accepted.

Comment: Is the delegate/data source set?